# Reuse a scikit learn model .pkl in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pickle

I am a beginner in AWS and I trained on my computer a RandomForestClassifier with scikit-learn and I used joblib to get my model in pkl format.

Now I would like, to reuse this RandomForest in AWS Lambda.
Since it needs sklearn.externals to load my model again, I have made a Zip directory which contains Numpy, Scipy, sklearn, my code and my model in pkl format.
I put this zip in a S3 bucket to execute my code in Lambda.

I would like to know if then, it is possible to use this model using model.predict() ? I didn't find any documentation about this specific problem.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but since sagemaker exists now I was hoping it would be more straight forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391639/is-it-possible-to-predict-in-sagemaker-without-using-s3

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I succeed using URLs. I put my model .pkl in a S3 Bucket, and I can get it using urllib2.

Here is my code, if anyone ever encounters the same problem :

```
req = urllib2.Request(url=url_model)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
model = cPickle.load(f)
```

It only works if the file is public. If you need it to be private, you can generate a presigned URL using boto3 like this :

```
url_model = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    ExpiresIn=1,
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
        'Key': 'mymodel.pkl'
    }
)
```